# Countdown Progress Bar not working Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I have written the following code to create a countdown progress bar in my android app:

```
ProgressBar gameTimer;
CountDownTimer gameCountDownTimer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gameTimer = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.game_timer);
    setTimer(10);
}

private void setTimer(int time) {
    progress = 100;
    final int actualTime = time*1000;
    gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
    gameCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(actualTime, 1000) {
        int totalTime = actualTime;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            progress = (int)(( totalTime - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)totalTime * 100);
            gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            progress = 0;
            gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
            endGame();
        }
    };
}
```

But the problem is that the timer is always filled. The timer is not counting down and is never finishing. What is wrong with the above code? How to make the progress bar countdown from the filled state to the empty state in the given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to start the `CountDownTimer`, try this:

```
private void setTimer(int time) {
    progress = 100;
    final int actualTime = time*1000;
    gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
    gameCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(actualTime, 1000) {
        int totalTime = actualTime;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            progress = (int)(( totalTime - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)totalTime * 100);
            gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            progress = 0;
            gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
            endGame();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

As it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

**EDIT:**

Your `ProgressBar` counts up because you misunderstood the `millisUntilFinishrd` variable. This variable decreases on each tick. So to make your ProgressBar count down, you have to replace this:

```
progress = (int)(( totalTime - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)totalTime * 100);
```

by this:

```
progress = (int)( millisUntilFinished  /(double)totalTime * 100);
```

Comment: Ok got it.. thanks.. but instead of counting down, the progress bar is counting up. What to do?

Comment: Try to replace this `( totalTime - millisUntilFinished )` by this `millisUntilFinished` on the `onTick` method.

Comment: A small issue left. I have written this `progress = 0;gameTimer.setProgress(progress);` in onFinish to set the progress to zero, but the progress is never becoming zero.

Comment: What is the final state of your `ProgressBar`?

Comment: It has to show no progress? Isn't that what yo meant by final state?

Comment: Just noticed, it is not showing the full progress as well. The progressbar varies from step below the full progress to one step above the no progress. I want it to be like from full progress to no progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56839/discussion-between-harikrishnan-t-and-g-t).

Comment: @G.T. What does the "double" in "(double)totalTime * 100);" do?  Why choose double here?